# Puppeteer slow down after a few hours

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm having some issues with my node app and it slowing down after a few hours on my EC2 server.

My app uses puppeteer, bull and mongodb, I have a bull queue which my app reads to process, once the job is complete it then writes the results to mongodb, so this process runs until the queue is complete (7000 jobs). When I start the app puppeteer takes around 5-10 seconds to return the results, the longer the process runs the slower it gets, after about 2-3 hours it starts taking 30-50 seconds to run a job. If I stop and start the process the jobs return back to the initial 5-10 seconds speed for 10 minutes until returning back to 30-50 seconds.

I've checked memory, it doesn't seem to be using excessive memory it stays around the same level the whole time. I've also checked the CPU and I don't think its running into any issues with that either.

Any ideas on what else could be causing the slot downs? I have noticed when the app starts the nodejs loop delay is 0.5ms after a few hours its around the 1-2ms range. Whats the best way to debug this?

Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I wonder if its a leak in Chrome? Have you tried restarting the browser (`await browser.close()`) while keeping your app alive? Maybe that will at least tell you if the leak is in Chrome or your app. I know Chrome desktop (non-headless) starts to wig out if I leave it open for many hours or days.

Comment: After each job I close both the page and the browser and reopen a new one.

Comment: I am facing the same issue with puppeteer and chrome my first process runs fine but when I try to run the same another time, the processing time will increases although I have closed the browser every time using the `await browser. close()`. Have you able to fix the problem @ElmosGotAGun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to close and re-open the browser for every session if you don't already. This is a tricky endeavor and can be hard to manage as you'll need to know some inner-workings of puppeteer to make sure everything is "wired right". I maintain a [docker image here](https://hub.docker.com/r/browserless/chrome/), <s>and the code to generate a clean instance of [Chrome per-session is here](https://github.com/joelgriffith/browserless/blob/master/src/Chrome.ts#L537)</s>. (dead link)